# Cannot create a client socket with a PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER context while trying to rank a player in-group

Tags: python, python-3.x, roblox

```py
import robloxapi

async def grouprank(userId, rankName):
    # omitted rank-name to role id mapping
    rankId = dic[rankName]
    client = robloxapi.Client(cookie=NOT_STUPID_ENOUGH_TO_DISCLOSE)
    grp = await client.get_group(32409863)
    await robloxapi.client.Group.set_rank_by_id(grp, userId, rankId)

import asyncio
lp = asyncio.new_event_loop()
lp.run_until_complete(grouprank(2315210162, "Recruit"))
```

The code above throws the following error:
ssl.SSLError: Cannot create a client socket with a PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER context (_ssl.c:795)

This code is mainly to rank a player to another rank in a roblox group using a bot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in the ssl library and there are MANY GitHub issues based on this. [For example, this one](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/issues/302) is a sample issue. For me, it worked by using `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context` in previous projects. Idk if it will work for Roblox because I don't have access to it.

Comment: It did not work for roblox but it's the best answer available here.